# Are there any Excel Code for undefined and differently texts to seperate

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This is my

**current data**
[image: data]

I want to seperate the values ; (number)-(number) monate,(number)-(number) Teilnehmer,(number)monate,1

**desired output** 
[image: output].

The data in all rows have  different length and character. The values that i want to seperate is also have same structure but different values. **There are over 3000 Rows I can't do that all manually**

Comment: Can you do it manually with Text to Columns?

Comment: Try using find() to locate the delimiters like "/" or " " and then left() and mid() to get the parts. There are many q&a on here with examples.

Comment: Check [Split text into different columns with the Convert Text to Columns Wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7).

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Your source data looks a little too complex for a straight forward text to columns.

Without a sample selection of input data, it's very difficult to test. Ideally, you should paste in several lines of sample data, showing each variation possible.

This untested code below might give you what you want. You just need to select the data (not the whole column) and then run the macro:

```
Sub try_this()

    Dim s(1 To 4), c As Range, arrWords()
    
    arrWords = Array("lzeit ", "Bildungsgutschein", "Teilnehmer")

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
    
    'look at start of string
        If IsNumeric(Left(c.Value, 1)) Then
            s(1) = 10 ' length of date
        Else
            s(1) = 19 ' length of non-date
        End If
        
        'write first section to cell to right
        c.Offset(, 1).Value = Trim(Left(c.Value, s(1)))
        
        'find Vollzeit/Teilzeit
        s(2) = InStr(s(1), c.Value, arrWords(0)) - 3
    
        'write duration to next cell on right
        c.Offset(, 2).Value = Trim(Mid(c.Value, s(1) + 1, s(2) - s(1) - 1))
        
        'write Vollzeit/Teilzeit to next cell on right
        c.Offset(, 3).Value = Trim(Mid(c.Value, s(2), 8))
        
        'find end of Bildungsgutschein
        s(3) = InStr(1, c.Value, arrWords(1)) + Len(arrWords(1))
        
        'write remainder of string to next cell on right
        c.Offset(, 4).Value = Trim(Mid(c.Value, s(2) + 8, s(3) - s(2) - 8))
        
        'find end of Teilnehmer
        s(4) = InStr(1, c.Value, arrWords(2)) + Len(arrWords(2))
        
        'if that word isn't found, reuse previous start point
        If s(4) = Len(arrWords(2)) Then s(4) = s(3)

        'write remainder of string to next cell on right
        c.Offset(, 5).Value = Trim(Mid(c.Value, s(3), s(4) - s(3)))
        
        'write remainder of string to next cell on right
        c.Offset(, 6).Value = Trim(Mid(c.Value, s(4)))

    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It seperates until the (number) - (number) Teilnehmer word .
Exp: 26.06.20237 / 5 Monate/ Vollzeit/blendedlearning Förderung mit bild.../ 
Can you also arrange the code again that it seperates the  (number) - (number) Teilnehmer word in to another cell itself if its possible ?

Comment: I've had a go, see edited answer - but without some actual paste-able sample data it's hard to tell if it's going to work.

Comment: If this code errors after on the xxxth row, I suggest you examine the xxxth row as it must not conform to the same structure as all previous rows. This further demonstrates why having actual data in your question **that can be copy/pasted into Excel** for testing purposes would help people answer your question.